# "conduct intakes"

Tags: vocabulary

What does *conduct intakes* mean when one says “a doctor is trained to conduct intakes”?

Is it something related to the amount of medication the patient will take?

Or is it something related to prescribing medication?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To  “conduct an intake” means to do the initial patient-interviewing necessary to admit a patient.  If you review [hospital intake forms](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1052&bih=570&q=hospital+intake+form&oq=hospital+intake+form&gs_l=img.12..0.3890.7108.0.8803.2.2.0.0.0.0.149.281.0j2.2.0....0...1ac..19.img.ZHqBN1YxNTA), you will see that they often are lengthy, detailed, and sometimes difficult to interpret.  Hence, conducting an intake quickly and accurately is a skill necessary to be developed, rather than a skill everyone has apriori.  It has nothing to do with prescribing medication.